# How to use Python 3 to extract text between certain html tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a web page containing the names of companies. The names are between  tags. The format is:

```
<option value="15589" id="optExhibitor15589" title="N571  Company One, Inc">N571 Company One, Inc</option>
<option value="16441" id="optExhibitor16441" title="N873  Company Two">Company Two</option>
<option value="14863" id="optExhibitor14863" title="N219  Company Three">N219 Company Three</option>
```

I've tried breaking the file into a list of lines using `.readline()` but I cannot figure out how to extract the text between the`title=` and `">`.

I have hundreds of these names I want to extract and I want to produce a list of the company names.

Comment: Can you use lxml or beautifulsoup?

Comment: This is web scraping, not screen scraping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use scrappy or other libraries for scraping, but since you already got what you need. This might help you to obtain the values:

```
a = '<option value="15589" id="optExhibitor15589" title="N571  Company One, Inc">N571 Company One, Inc</option>'
beginning = a.find('title=') # Returns the integer at the location of 'title'
end = a.find('\">') # Returns the integer at the closing tag
print(a[beginning+6:end+1])
```

gives this output:
`"N571  Company One, Inc"`